# Implicit declaration of function ‘fopen_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] FILE *f = fopen_s(stdin);

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fopen

Hi I am getting the following error from my compiler, please help!

FROM COMPILER:   main.c: In function ‘main’: main.c:25:13: warning: implicit declaration of function

fopen_s’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]    FILE *f = fopen_s(stdin);              ^~~~~~~

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
        //FILE *f ;

     int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     int charCount = 0;
     int wordCount = 0;
     int lineCount = 0;
     int doChar    = 0;
     int doWord    = 0;
     int doLine    = 0;
     int inWord    = 0;
     int c         = 0;
     char *fileName = 0;
     FILE *f = fopen_s(stdin);

// prompt user to enter filename
        printf("Please enter a filename: \n");
//  fgetwc(f);
//loop
        while (argv++, -- argc) {
        if (!strcmp(*argv, "-c"))       doChar = 1;
        else if (!strcmp(*argv, "-w"))  doWord = 1;
        else if ( !strcmp(*argv, "-l")) doLine = 1;
        else if (!( f = fopen((fileName = *argv),"r"))) {
            printf("Usage: wc [-1] [-w] [-c]\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (!(doChar || doWord || doLine)) {
        doChar = doWord = doLine= 1;
    }
    while(EOF !=( c= fgetc(f)))
    {
        charCount++;
    }
        if (c == '\n') {
             lineCount++;
         }
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            if (!inWord){
                {inWord = 1; wordCount++;}
            }
            else {
                inWord = 0;
            }
        }
    if (doLine){
         printf("%8d\n",lineCount);
     }
    if (doWord){
        printf("%8d\n", wordCount);
    }
    if(doChar){
        printf("%8d\n",charCount );
    }
    if (fileName) {
        printf(" %s\n",fileName);
    }
    printf("\n" );
}
```

Comment: Please be careful with your tag selection. It was C#, and you could not reach the correct audience with that. I changed your tags as I see appropriate. Adding the name of the compiler, the system you are working on etc. can be better.

Comment: What do you expect the line causing the warning to do?  What is this `fopen_s()` function called on that line (there is a non-portable function with this name, but you don't say which platform you are using)?   Perhaps you meant to write `f = fdopen(STDIN_FILENO, "r");` (and to `#include <unistd.h>`).